# SQL Server: Simple COUNT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to count the number of times "on" occurs in multiple columns. This first query returns exactly what I want but when I try the 2nd query, it only returns the column headings with no results. I'm just getting back into sql if someone could tell me what's wrong.

This query returns the desired results:

```
DECLARE @MainHospital varchar(50)='HOSPITAL 1';

SELECT 
    mainhospital, COUNT([chkInpatient]) as 'Inpatient Count'
FROM 
    SurveyPicList
WHERE 
    MainHospital = @MainHospital 
    AND chkInpatient = 'on'
GROUP BY 
    MainHospital
```

This returns only the 5 column headings, but no results:

```
DECLARE @MainHospital varchar(50)='HOSPITAL 1';

SELECT 
    mainhospital, 
    COUNT([chkInpatient]) AS 'Inpatient Count', 
    COUNT([chkPartB]) AS 'PartB Count', 
    COUNT([chkOutpatient]) AS 'Outpatient Count', 
    COUNT([chkER]) AS 'ER Count'
FROM 
    SurveyPicList
WHERE 
    MainHospital = @MainHospital 
    AND chkInpatient = 'on' 
    AND chkPartB = 'on' 
    AND chkOutpatient = 'on' 
    AND chkER = 'on'
GROUP BY 
    MainHospital
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that you want to count each column individually.  Use condition aggregation, rather than a `where` clause:

```
DECLARE @MainHospital varchar(50)='HOSPITAL 1';

SELECT mainhospital,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [chkInpatient] = 'on' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Inpatient Count",
       SUM(CASE WHEN [chkPartB] = 'on' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'PartB Count',
       SUM(CASE WHEN [chkOutpatient] = 'on' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Outpatient Count",
       SUM(CASE WHEN [chkER] = 'on' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "ER Count"
FROM SurveyPicList
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
GROUP BY MainHospital;
```

The reason your query doesn't work is that no row has all four columns set to `on`, which is what you are requiring in that `where` clause.

Note that I also changed the column aliases to use double quotes.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: works perfect and that makes sense regarding my `where` clause, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your second query is looking for cases where chkInpatient, chkPartB, chkOutpatient and chkER are all 'on' for **each** record.  Is that why you're not getting any records returned?